# node js socket.io not working on mobile

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io

We have created a chat application with node js in a shared hosting. hosting has enabled auto SSl. 
In desktop socket.io is working, we have give port 8080. But in mobile socket.io not working.
Please help us how to overcome this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's not enough close to enough information here for us to help.  There's no code.  There's nothing about the configuration of the server.  We don't know what "auto SSI" is.  We don't know what the network configuration is.  We don't know how you're trying to connect to your server.  We don't know if there's a firewall involved (home or work).

Comment: Auto SSL is a new feature built in to cPanel which accommodates recent changes on the internet which make it more important for all sites to have an SSL certificate to be serving content securely to visitors. 
In desktop socket.io running perfectly but in mobile device(android), socket.io not connecting. We have set socket port 8080.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please elaborate the problem. What do mean by not working?
First check for the browser whether it supports websocket or not.
Usually chrome will support.

Comment: The chat application build using php & node js. When we are checking it on desktop machine it is working fine there but when we are checking in mobile device(android), it is not working i.e. socket is not connecting in mobile devices. Our application is running on secure socket leyer(SSL). Please tell us how can we overcome this problem. Thanks,

Comment: We have checking on google chrome browser in mobile device(Android) but unfortunately socket.io not connecitong. We have set socket port 8080.